# How to use "due date"?

Tags: word-choice

Am I using "due date" correctly if I write "Task A due date" in a calendar if you mean that Task A should be competed on this day. Or should it be "due today" or something else?

Comment: You can write whatever you want as long as you remember what you intended it to mean when the date rolls around.  *Task A due*, *Task A due today*, *Task A due date* are all fine calendar entries. Calendar entries are not typically subject to full English grammar rules- kinda like newspaper headlines.

Comment: @Jim Except for the last sentence, why not make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The assignment's due date is 25 Dec

or

> The assignment is due on 25 Dec

means the assignment has to be submitted by 25 Dec.

Comment: If more specific timing is required, sometimes more explicit info is given as well, e.g., "The assignment is due by noon on Oct 31," or, "The assignment is due 31 Oct COB," COB meaning "close of business." Such practices are not uncommon in the workplace. Either way, though, Jasper is right: the date specifies the last possible day the assignment can be submitted, and it wouldn't be late until the following day.